# Linear model for paired data

Tags: regression, linear-model, paired-data, lm

We have 100 subjects of varying and known age and sex with two strongly related dependent variables (X, Z) measured with two methods (A and B). Method B is known and expected to show more reduced values. The variables X and Z can be used to group the subjects in several categories.

The recommended practice in this case is creating a hierarchical model (lme4...).

What about a linear model of differences? This would provide easily understandable results to interpret the differences, and it is somewhat loosely related to the classic Bland-Altmann method comparison. Is this still fallacious if I include the original value in the equation? It seems so easy it must be wrong:

lm($X_{A}-X_{B}$ ~ Age + Sex + $X_{A}$); lm($Z_{A}-Z_{B}$ ~ Age + Sex + $Z_{A}$);

lm($X_{A}-X_{B}$ ~ Age + Sex);        lm($Z_{A}-Z_{B}$ ~ Age + Sex);